# How to get network printer status using C# socket?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, printing, network-printers

I have an ASP .NET Web API and network printer(Epson TM-U220). I need to get the printer status on the Epson code and I just try as below. But I've only got printer-ready status. When the status is like printer busy, out of paper, door open, and others then the socket is waiting and API is crashed. Not get any response such a situation.

```
var server = "<Printer IP Address>";

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(server);
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

var command = "" + (char)27 + (char)97 + (char)14;  //Epson command to get printer status
byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);

clientSocket.Send(commandBytes );
var statusCode = clientSocket.Receive(commandBytes );
clientSocket.Close();
```

If the Printer is ready, statusCode got 3. Not getting any other codes.